# Is anyone using a firefox XUL IDE?

Tags: firefox, ide, xul

I'm not interested in Firebug, a XUL debugger, or a JavaScript editor, but a true WYSIWYG IDE for XUL form design.

Comment: +1: no, but if you find one please let us know!

Comment: I have been searching such a tool for 2 years. No luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MozillaWiki page with [a list XUL Integrated Development Environments](https://wiki.mozilla.org/XUL:IDE) and descriptions of each.

Answer (score 4):

I use [XUL Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Explorer) for doing quick mock-ups of things or checking out elements with which I'm not familiar.  It's not WYSIWYG, but you can drag and drop elements.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to note that I do XUL development with [ActiveState KomodoEdit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/). It doesn't have WYSIWYG XUL gui design but it recognizes XUL files and can give you code hints for the XUL namespace as well as their corresponding JS files.

Note that Komodo was written in XUL as well. It works very well for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is one Wysiwyg editor called [XUL Gear](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/162046/)

Answer (score 2):

Spket IDE has no WYSIWIG either.

You may want to try Extension Developer at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7434, which is a Firefox add-on. One screenshot on that page illustrates an WYSIWIG XUL editor. You can edit an XUL file with Spket IDE and load it with this editor to check the final effect.

Comment: It's not exactly wysiwyg though, it's "hey, the rendering updates as you type in the code".

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/)'s XUL layout editor. I recall that it is very complete and easy to use, and it comes with lots of examples of every single XUL element put in multiple layout scenarios. I believe you need a nightly build or a dev release of it, which you can easily get from the website.

The good thing is that besides the editor, it comes with some other fancy and very useful XUL developer tools. And of course, it is a great iTunes replacement ;)

Comment: I downloaded Songbird, and found the XUL developer toolkit and the XUL periodic table, but couldn't find this XUL layout editor that you were referring to.  Can you give a more direct link to the layout editor.

Comment: You have to download the addon for Songbird called "Songbird Developer Tools", which is updated for Songbird 1.1.0, not 1.1.1.

One of the tools that will appear on the "Tools" menu is called "Xul Editor", which combined with "XUL Periodic Table" gives a quite acceptable way to build XUL Layout.

Comment: "Xul Editor" in "Songbird Developer Tools" is actually a copy of "Live XUL Editor" from the Extension developer's extension: http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/extensiondev/xuledit.png

Answer (score 0):

I think no Wysiwyg IDE available for Xul
but there is [Spket IDE](http://www.spket.com/), it may help you