# WYSIWYG Editor for XUL

Tags: wysiwyg, xul

Can anybody recommend a good graphic WYSIWYG editor for XUL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494125/is-anyone-using-a-firefox-xul-ide) is very similar: [XUL Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Explorer) is probably as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 4):

If you need WYSIWYG XUL editor, try [XUL Gear](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/162046/) FireFox extension

Comment: I just updated the Mozilla-wiki page on XUL:IDE - https://wiki.mozilla.org/XUL%3aIDE - , and XUL Gear seems to be the only project in active development (with a July, 2010 update)

Answer (score 3):

Or the "Live XUL Editor" in the [Extension developer's extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7434).

There's no drag-and-drop editor like for Windows Forms if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a MozillaWiki page with [a list XUL Integrated Development Environments](https://wiki.mozilla.org/XUL%3aIDE) and descriptions of each.

Answer (score 1):

I've been known to use the DOM Inspector to design XUL, but then again I'm quite happy coding in vi and reloading the window.